# Run powershell Get-Computerinfo remotely with invoke-command gives me a strange formatted answer

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have this command that collects some infro from a remote server.

```
$ComputerInfo = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $FQDN -ScriptBlock { Get-ComputerInfo -Property OsName, OsProductType }
```

If I chech the results with this code:

```
$ComputerInfo
$ComputerInfo.OsName
$ComputerInfo.OsProductType
```

I get this answer:

> OsName         : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
>
> OsProductType  : Server PSComputerName : SESTODS057.sweco.se
>
> RunspaceId     : 07954177-8d94-42d5-99ce-d2ae4a33f435   Microsoft
> Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
>
> Value : Server

It's the last value above that I have problem with. **Why does OsProductType look like a sub object** or something?

Same commands ran locally

```
$ComputerInfo = Get-ComputerInfo -Property OsName, OsProductType 
$ComputerInfo
$ComputerInfo.OsName
$ComputerInfo.OsProductType
```

Gives this answer:

> OsName        : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
>
> OsProductType : Server
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
>
> Server

Which is what I expected.

Why this? How can I solve this, so I get the same answer when I run it remotely?

Comment: Run `$ComputerInfo.GetType()` with the result from your local call, and `$ComputerInfo.GetType()` with the remote result. What do you see?

Comment: I don't see the issue.  It shows `OsProductType : Server` for both.  What do you mean by subtype or something?  What do you have an issue with?

Comment: This is the gettype() answer from both remote and local calls.
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                 
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Comment: What I mean is I got this answer when remote: Value : Server I can actually get the value only if I call $ComputerInfo.OsProductType.Value. So that's a work around. But still why is it different? And why just for that property?

Comment: If you look at `$ComputerInfo.OsProductType.GetType()` you wil see it is a [System.Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.producttype?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0). If you want the **numeric** value of that instead of the Enum name, do `$ComputerInfo.OsProductType..value__`

Comment: When I run `$ComputerInfo.OsProductType.GetType()` locally it says it's a System.Enum. But when run remotely it is System.ValueType. So why is it different?

Comment: @Perre because remoting.  If I had to guess, serialization causes the enum to be transformed.

Comment: the `PSComputerName` and `RunspaceID` props come from using `Invoke-Command`. those are auto-added by that cmdlet ... and are hidden by default. you will need to add an `-ExcludeProperty` list to get rid of them.